# Regarding nokia mobile browser simulator java error

Tags: java, nokia, fatal-error

I'm trying to install Nokia Mobile Browser Simulator but it's gave the following error :-

Fatal Error

Invocation of this Java Application has caused an
InvocationTargetException. This application will now exit. (LAX)

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.zerog.ia.installer.IAStatusLog.a(Unknown Source)
at ZeroGbg.a(Unknown Source)
at ZeroGbg.c(Unknown Source)
at ZeroGbg.e(Unknown Source)
at ZeroGbg.a(Unknown Source)
at ZeroGbg.a(Unknown Source)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.Main.b(Unknown Source)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.Main.main(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at             sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.zerog.lax.LAX.launch(Unknown Source)
at com.zerog.lax.LAX.main(Unknown Source)
```

please solve my problem why this error occur :